# I am trying to convert some Strings I received from my mongodb collection into a java date object. But I can't seem to find a pattern that works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, datetime, spring-mongodb

I want to convert values from my mongoDB format into a java Date object(LocalDateTime would also be fine). But I can't find the pattern that does the job.

My 'lastupdated' value inside the mongodb collection is like this.
`lastupdated : "2015-08-26 00:03:50.133000000"`

I have successfully created a connection but I am getting an error converting it from a string to a date. This is what the error I am being shown.
`Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.util.Date] for value '2015-08-31 00:41:20.670000000'`

I am also struggling to convert this kind of String with key 'release'.

> release : '1893-05-09T00:00:00.000+00:00;

I have applied the DateTimeFormat annotation which has usually worked for me in Spring as shown below.

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSZ")
    private Date lastupdated;
```

I have also tried other similar variations such as

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S")
    private Date lastupdated;
```

For my other String, I tried this.

```
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'")
    private String released;`
```

I have looked through the pattern documentation linked here.
https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#patterns

I am not able find the right format I believe, or perhaps there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: You want to avoid using `Date`. It’s a legacy class that was finally supplanted nearly 10 years ago because it was poorly designed. Use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html).

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the wrong Java type as well. That type cannot represent a point on the timeline as it has only a date with time but no time zone nor offset-from-UTC.

Comment: Never put `Z` inside quotes in a date-time formatting pattern. You are discarding valuable information: an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds.

Comment: This question is convoluted and unclear. I suggest you show an utterly simple but complete example of storing a date-time value, and of retrieving that date-time value. This question is also likely a duplicate of others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that if a date that is saved as a type String inside MongoDB, the default mapper cannot read it as a Java Date or LocalDateTime object. It has be mapped to a java String (unless you create the mapper function yourself). I could be wrong but that is the conclusion I have come to.